# Evaluate: $\lim_\limits{x\to3}\frac{\sin(x+1)}{2x(x-3)}$

Tags: calculus

I am attempting to evaluate the limit:

$$\lim_\limits{x\to3}\frac{\sin(x+1)}{2x(x-3)}$$

I have stared at this limit for 20 min and cant seem to find an angle to attack it, was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction to solving this limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $\pi < 4 < \dfrac 32\pi$ we have that

- $\sin (x+1) \to \sin 4 <0$

and then

$$\lim_\limits{x\to3^+}\frac{\sin(x+1)}{2x(x-3)}=-\infty$$

$$\lim_\limits{x\to3^-}\frac{\sin(x+1)}{2x(x-3)}=\infty$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: what do you mean by sin 4 < 0?

Comment: @user196104 4 radians are equal to about 230° and therefore $\sin 4 <0$.

Comment: @user196104 or $\pi < 4 < \dfrac 32\pi$ implies $4$ radians is in the third quadrant implies $\sin 4 < 0$

Comment: All that really matters is that $\sin4\neq0$.

Comment: @stevengregory in that way it is more clear I update that!

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes of course for the not existence the key point is that $\sin 4 \neq 0$. My aim was also give the values for the one side limits.

Comment: @gimusi - No. I'm deleting the comment.